# Is it possible to capture and store the video streams in each room in p2p webrtc streaming?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video-capture

I came across a solution named Zipcall

[zip call github repo](https://github.com/ianramzy/decentralized-video-chat)

ZipCall connects user streams via p2p webRTC connection

My need is , I need to store the web cam videos of members in each room in a separate room folders in the server ?

What is the way to capture the streams in webrtc p2p room and store it ?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to record client-side using `MediaRecorder` to record client-side and then send the file to the server.

To actually record server-side you would have to use an SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) like `Mediasoup` or `janus-gateway` for example. Then all the video traffic will go through the server and you can attach it to `ffmpeg` or `gstreamer` to record it.